# Why can't android projects be imported into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a root directory with a number of android eclipse projects inside.  They all have .project files, but eclipse does not seem to see them as eclipse projects?  Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: How are you trying to import them into the workspace? List your steps. How did the root folder with eclipse projects get created? Where did they come from?

Answer (score 1):

Cause for not importing projects in eclipse :

**Reason 1 :  Project Structure Differs**

**Reason 2 :  Project Configuration files missing or not available**

**Reason 3 :  Project can be already exists in workspace**

**Reason 4 :  Don't have Proper and Standard Naming Convention**

Answer (score 0):

You have to import them manually

- First `File > Import`
- Then `General > Existing Project Into Workspace`
- Either select root directory or Select archive file, click Browse to locate the directory or file containing the project that you want to import
- Under `Projects` select the project that you want to import
- Finally click finish to import the project

Here is a link to the eclipse help section on this

- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

Hope you have android sdk and ADT plugin for eclipse.

File-->Import-->Android-->Existing Android code into workspace.

Then import the projects from your root directory using Browse button. If you don't have ADT plugin definitely you never import your android projects.